# Straight lines with rational gradient

Tags: probability

Wondering if it makes sense to ask:

In $(x,y)$ plane what probability has an arbitrary straight line $y=mx+c$ to have a rational slope $m$? I.e., referencing to an infinitely large sheet of standard grid lines (with given origin, coordinate axes horizontal and vertical) made up of unit squares, what percentage of lines pass through rational points?

If a random straight line is drawn through a fixed point of  rational coordinates then many near misses from other grid points can be observed.

Comment: It's actually not sufficient for $m$ to be rational to have the line pass through rational points.  Regardless of whether $m$ is rational, you'll need either $c$ to also be rational or you will require $\frac{c}{m}$ to be rational. Interestingly, if $m$ is irrational you can still pass through rational points provided that $c$ is a rational multiple of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is unsatisfying: 0.  The percentage of rational numbers in any given interval is zero, as seen in [Percentage of rational numbers on an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022176/percentage-of-rational-numbers-on-an-interval)